# extract and plot all highways from pbf or osm format

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I have a Polygon with next coords:

```
[
        [
          71.224365234375,
          54.303704439898084
        ],
        [
          74.8663330078125,
          54.303704439898084
        ],
        [
          74.8663330078125,
          55.727110085045986
        ],
        [
          71.224365234375,
          55.727110085045986
        ],
        [
          71.224365234375,
          54.303704439898084
        ]
      ]
```

I cannot find any ways how to extract all highways inside this polygon using something like osmium\osmosis\geopandas\geopy etc.. I want to get coordinates of this highways and names of these streets and after that show them on the plot using matplotlib.

Does anyone know how to get this(or all) info from osm\pbf format to pandas format..?

Comment: Please ask a specific question, but `osmconvert` might help: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/9816/the-best-way-to-extract-street-list

Comment: @MauriceMeyer ok, I need to get all streets (lat lons, names, their maxspeed, oneway yes or no) from pbf \ osm format